# Проблема с кодом

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

ТАКАЯ беда у меня с права полоса белая не знаю как убрать это раз а во вторых не могу задать размер иконки телефона. в Font-Awesome.

```css
text-decoration:none !important;
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "OpenSansRegular", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0 !importam;
  padding: 0;
  border: none !importam;
}

.h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "OpenSansLight", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: em(43);
}

.h2 {
  font-size: em(34);
}

.h3,
h4 {
  font-family: "OpenSansSemibold", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: em(17);
}

h4 {
  font-size: em(15);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.main-head {
  background-image: url(img/bg_top.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.mnu_line {
  padding-top: 48px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-mnu {
  font-size: em(15px);
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.main-mnu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  color: #7e91a4;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.main-mnu ul li a:hover {
  color: #414e56;
}

.active a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #414e56;
}

.phone {
  text-align: right;
}

.phone-wrap {
  display: block;
  color: #414e5b;
  font-family: "Exo2Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: em(22px);
}

.fa.fa-mobile {
  font-size: em(500px)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main-head">

    <div class="conteiner">
      <div class="row">


        <div class="mnu_line clearfix">

          <div class="col-md-2">

            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Ovk"></a>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-7">
            <div class="phone">

              <div class="phone-wrap"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>+38(068) 6847810
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="callback">Заказать обратный звонок</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 col-md-pull-2">

            <nav class="main-mnu">
              <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs for you</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Haw we work</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас какой-то элемент выпирает за границы окна. Вам лучше поискать его через инспектор, хотя конечно, есть простой способ побороть эту проблему:

```
body{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Что касается иконок, попробуйте так:

```
.fa.fa-mobile:before {
  font-size: 500px
}
```

`em()` это вообще что такое? Может быть вы хотели сделать высоту в em? тогда она записывается так: `2em`

Еще ошибки:

`!importam` -> `!important`

Comment: Спасибо помог увеличить иконку. Но белую полосу первым кодом так и не удалось исправить. Некоторые елементы выходят но хз что с этим делать.

Comment: <div class="conteiner"> - должно быть container. Многие теги в коде у вас не закрыты.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас у элемента с классом .row стоят margin'ы с минусами непонятно зачем. Уберите их и все будет хорошо.

[image: .row]

**UPD**

Или не используйте .row класс

Comment: Редактировать популярную стороннюю библиотеку идея так себе

Comment: @andreymal ну тогда можно не использовать .row класс

Comment: класс row надо использовать с классом col-, вот и все. Это же Бутстрап.

Answer (score 0):

Для задания размера иконок нужно изменить размер шрифта, можно задать напрямую для иконки или для блока в котором иконка. Иконки работают как текст, поэтому задание размера такое же как для текста. Задайте правильные значение  `font-size: em(22px);` значения в  `em` пишутся вот так `2em`, размер получается в два раза больше чем размер шрифта родителя

```
.row{
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-right:-15px;
}
```

тут все правильно, это стандартные значения для бутстрапа, а вот тут ошибка
у вас `div class="conteiner"`, а нужно `div class="container"`

Comment: друг который сказал что нужно поменять контейнер, спасибо. Я поменял и всё стало на свои места, а так весь день мучился.

Answer (score 0):

**Проверьте Ваш код на ошибки!**

`.contAiner` , а не `.conteiner`

`!important`, а не  `!importam`

`a {text-decoration:none !important; }`  , а не `text-decoration:none !important;`

и т.д (точки, точки с запятой, [пересчет шрифтов](http://pxtoem.com/))

```css
a {text-decoration:none !important; }
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-family: "OpenSansRegular", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0 !importam;
  padding: 0;
  border: none !important;
}

.h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "OpenSansLight", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 2.6875em;
}

.h2 {
  font-size: 2.125em;
}

.h3,
h4 {
  font-family: "OpenSansSemibold", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.0625em;
}

h4 {
  font-size: .9375em;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.main-head {
  background-image: #333;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.mnu_line {
  padding-top: 48px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-mnu {
  font-size: .9375em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.main-mnu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  color: #7e91a4;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.main-mnu ul li a:hover {
  color: #414e56;
}

.active a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #414e56;
}

.phone {
  text-align: right;
}

.phone-wrap {
  display: block;
  color: #414e5b;
  font-family: "Exo2Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
}

.fa.fa-mobile {
  font-size: 31.25em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main-head">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">


        <div class="mnu_line clearfix">

          <div class="col-md-2">

            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Ovk"></a>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-7">
            <div class="phone">

              <div class="phone-wrap"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>+38(068) 6847810
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="callback">Заказать обратный звонок</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 col-md-pull-2">

            <nav class="main-mnu">
              <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs for you</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Haw we work</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Частенько помогает (не всегда) проверка на валидацию: [html](https://validator.w3.org/) , [css](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)